# How to use sendkeys to web element for large text values of nearly 10000 characters?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pass large text to the web element of about 10000 characters.
I tried using send keys and it is taking huge time
I tried to copy and paste using COntrol+v in send keys and chrome is getting hanged

Driver.Findelementbyxpath("//*(@id=""MSG_Add_1span"")").sendkeys (Driver.Keys.Control & "v")
Driver.Findelementbyxpath("//*(@id=""MSG_Add_1span"")").sendkeys b
b is variable where i Stored my larget text

Comment: Yep. It takes time to type 10000 characters, even for someone fast on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('gbqfq'));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + longstring +"')", inputField);
```

Comment: HI Bro can you please share this in VBA?

Comment: ((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver).ExecuteScript("your code"));